# Is it possible to set default transition animation for all application in AOSP?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-source

I described my problem in title. 
May be you have some ideas how to do it?

I can customize any part of AOSP.

Comment: do you want change default transition between two activity ?

Comment: Actualy no.
Let me describe some example
We have installed few applications in our device. 
Applications  haven't any customization of transition animation for activities, fragments, etc.
I want to do some changes in aosp in order to add default transition animation for every activity in every application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pein,

I have not specifically set a default transition for android, but I did find a place that might be a good starting point. Try looking in: frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

There is a section titled "Standard animations for a full-screen window or activity." (~ln 78). Try editing the corresponding animation (frameworks/base/core/res/res/anim/...) to see if it changes all of the corresponding animations.

Comment: Hi Michael, 
Thanks for answer it is correct, but I want to add something :)
In frameworks/base/core/res/res/values we have themes.xml
Thera is a base theme for all activities and there is param: <item name="windowAnimationStyle">@style/Animation.Activity</item>
So, in order to change animation for all we can change it in style/Animation.Activity.

Comment: I am glad that worked for you! Good luck with your ROM. 
P.S. I used a useful tool called OpenGrok to look through the source code (https://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/). It makes finding items like this a little easier. :)